# Unable to Display Name Caption Label for Various Images in Carousel View

Tags: swift, xcode, carousel, icarousel

I have a carousel view to my view controller to display images. I am trying to set a name label for each image which appears while scrolling through the Carousel View. But, when I use the following if/else statement to set the nameLabel field it is not changing with different images on the carousel view. Can anyone please let me know what is the problem ion my code? Appreciate your help!

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width/1.4, height: 300))
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    
    let imageview = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
    view.addSubview(imageview)
    imageview.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    imageview.image = UIImage(named: "Image_\(index+1)")

    if (imageview.image == UIImage(named: "Image_1")) {
        
        NameLabel.text = "Cat"
        
    }
    if (imageview.image == UIImage(named: "Image_2")) {
        
        NameLabel.text = "Dog"
        
    }
    if (imageview.image == UIImage(named: "Image_3")) {
        
        NameLabel.text = "Rat"
        
    }
    
    if (imageview.image == UIImage(named: "Image_4")) {
        
        NameLabel.text = "Tiger"
        
    }
    if (imageview.image == UIImage(named: "Image_5")) {
        
        NameLabel.text = "Leopard"
        
    }
    if (imageview.image == UIImage(named: "Image_6")) {
        
        NameLabel.text = "Squirrel"
        
    }
    return view
    
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with iCarousel but it looks like this method is not a good one to determine current focused cell. Maybe you have something like `didScroll`? And there you should check which cell is current (centered, focused) and therefore change the label.

Comment: Also I think comparing UIImages is not a good practise, you'd better compare indices.
`if (index == 3)) { NameLabel.text = "Rat" }`

Comment: @TiranUt Thanks for the help! But, I can't find any method named didScroll in iCarousel. Is there anything else than I can try? Thanks!

Comment: Try this one http://joxi.ru/E2p46oDiazL5Q2